# Sending E-mail As Another User

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is it possible to configure the user's mailbox to send emails on behalf but the message will be stored in the mailbox of another user and not in the senders mailbox?

I know that it possible only if the users mail box configured as primary but i don't want it.  i tried to give send as  permissions but it still the same.

please help.

Comment: You cannot literally send email as somebody else, you can say it is from that user, but unless you have control over their account it can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another mailbox as a separate Exchange account to Outlook profile of the first user. No other ways.